# Postman unable to read the body

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, postman, mongoose-schema

The following code gives an Validation error whenever the post/get request is made using postman. The image is also provided at the end of the code please check that out to debug this code.

```
****//this is my index file code****  

const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const dotenv  =require("dotenv");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
//importing the routes file
const Authroute = require("./routes/auth");

dotenv.config();


//middlewear
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.raw());
app.use("/api/users",Authroute);


//Connected to Db 

mongoose.connect(process.env.Db_Connect, 
{ useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, () =>
    {
    console.log("connected to Db");
});




app.listen(4000, ()=> console.log("your system is up"));




**//this is auth file code**
const router = require("express").Router();


const Newposts =require("../Models/posts");


//post request
router.post("/register",async(req,res) => 
{   
    const com = new Newposts({

      name:req.body.name,
      email:req.body.email,
      password:req.body.password,
    }); 
    try{
           const savedUser = await com.save();
              
              res.json(savedUser);
           
        
         }
    catch(err)
    {
        res.status(400).send(err);
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

error statement

```
"errors": {
    "name": {
        "name": "ValidatorError",
        "message": "Path `name` is required.",
        "properties": {
            "message": "Path `name` is required.",
            "type": "required",
            "path": "name"
        },
        "kind": "required",
        "path": "name"
    },
    "email": {
        "name": "ValidatorError",
        "message": "Path `email` is required.",
        "properties": {
            "message": "Path `email` is required.",
            "type": "required",
            "path": "email"
        },
        "kind": "required",
        "path": "email"
    },
    "password": {
        "name": "ValidatorError",
        "message": "Path `password` is required.",
        "properties": {
            "message": "Path `password` is required.",
            "type": "required",
            "path": "password"
        },
        "kind": "required",
        "path": "password"
    }
},
"_message": "posts validation failed",
"name": "ValidationError",
"message": "posts validation failed: name: Path `name` is required., email: Path `email` is required., password: Path `password` is required."
```

}

posts file code

```
   const mongoose =require("mongoose");

const NewUser = new mongoose.Schema({
  name:{
        type: String,
        required:true,
        min:6,
        max:20
  },
  email:{
        type: String,
        required:true,
        min:10,
        max:200
  },
  password:{
        type: String,
        required:true,
        min:6,
        max:100
  }


});

module.exports = mongoose.model("posts",NewUser);
```

[postman request link] Image

: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiO74.png

Thank you for your time....

Comment: Post your request body and avoid screenshots, add actual code.

Comment: ok  as per your say now I have edit my last post. Please take a quick look if u can..

Comment: Can you please add the postman request body?

Comment: POST: http://localhost:4000/api/users/register

Comment: Dear friend body  Form data -  check image - `https://miro.medium.com/max/984/1*REFX7IRRkjjHcKwhNWiJEg.png`

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQZ5j.png [Sorry for my silly mistake here is the screenshot of the postman body]